# Question about the motion of a ball attached to a string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, angular-velocity

The question I'm trying to answer is below:

[image]

For part a), I tried to use Newton's law $F_un=ma$. I know that $F_un=-\frac{\lambda}{l}x + mg$, so $m\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=-\frac{\lambda}{l}x + mg$ which would give $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + \frac{\lambda}{ml}x=g$. But this would imply that $\frac{\lambda}{ml}x=w^2x$ which I don't think is true since the ball will have harmonic motion meaning $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=-w^2x=\frac{\lambda}{l}x + mg$.

Now, part b) also confuses me because me in the equlibirum position $\frac{\lambda}{l}x_e=mg$ which would mean that the extension "$x$" used in part b) is not the actual extension and that the actual extension is $x-x_e$.

So I'm wondering if anyone can clear up my confusions with part a) and part b) of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is fine and the value for $\omega^2$ that you found is correct as is your value for $x_o$.

In your differential equation introduce another variable $y$ which is the displacement from the equilibrium position, so $y = x-x_o \rightarrow x = y + x_o$
Remembering that $x_o$ is a constant substitute for $x$ into the differential equation $$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + \frac{\lambda}{ml}x=g$$

Use the relationship that you have found for $x_o$ to eliminate $g$ and what do you get?
I hope the normal differential equation that you have learnt about in your lectures but in variable $y$ the displacement from the equilibrium position.

The setter of the problem made it more difficult by measuring displacements from an extreme of the motion.